# Connecting to MySQL through Objective-C (Desktop)

Tags: mysql, objective-c, theory

I've been searching for resources to be able to connect to MySQL through Objective-C (a desktop application, not iOS) and I can't seem to find anything newly relevant that works. Since it's desktop based would I be able to skip using middleware (JSON/XML)? And sorry for the lack of a better term but am I right in saying Objective-C for the desktop, and not iOS or is there another word for Objective-C for the desktop?

Any help in regards to connecting to MySQL and upping my terminology would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do, using a middleman such as PHP may be easier, but you can accomplish directly connecting using sockets.

Take a look at this. http://macbug.org/macosxsample/mysql#.Ui9xLT5s25c

Also keep in mind your MySQL server must be configured to allow remote connections from your IP address.